# What happened to the stack exchange app for iOS?

Tags: support

The stackexchange app would no longer launch, I tried to reload it from the Mac App Store, and it’s not there (or at least, I could not find it).

I probably missed some event, is there an alternative?

Comment: This announcement was posted yesterday on [meta.se]: [Turning off the mobile feed for the Stack Exchange app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366936). (It is among the most recent posts [tagged ios-app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-app).)

Comment: @TheAmplitwist The post you linked contains also this link: [Stack Overflow Mobile app removed from iOS App Store?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385599#385622)  (Although it is from 2019.) I have seen also this recent post on [meta.se]: [Is the StackExchange app no longer available on the App Store?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366943)  It was closed as a duplicate of: [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348075)

Comment: For what it's worth, it's should still show up in the "purchased" items under your account.

Comment: A recent announcement on [meta.se]: [Mobile app infrastructure being decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026).

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for a stack exchange mobile client, I’ve just made a full stack exchange client (it includes 380+ channels). Here is the App Store link: https://apps.apple.com/it/app/crew-for-exchange/id1547171709?l=en

Comment: Did you create it ?

Comment: @S.M.T Yes I did!